# How to use GestureDetector with CustomPaint?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have draggable cards with nodes that I can tap on. After tapping on nodes, a path will be drawn between cards. I want to add some functionalities to the path.

I have a few problems with this. Is it possible not to specify the size inside CustomPaint? If I have to, how do I update hit test's detection area after the card is dragged? (Currently, It's not at the right place, the hit test area won't update its location along with the card.)

Here is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dial_infinite_canvas/src/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:dial_infinite_canvas/src/domain/model/edge.dart';

class EdgeWidget extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const EdgeWidget({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _EdgeWidgetState();
}

class _EdgeWidgetState extends ConsumerState<EdgeWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: EdgePainter(ref),
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.amber,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class EdgePainter extends CustomPainter {
  WidgetRef ref;
  EdgePainter(this.ref);
  Path p = Path();
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()..color = Colors.blue;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint.strokeWidth = 10;

    var node = ref.watch(connectedNodeListProvider);
    var start = ref.watch(startKeyProvider);
    var end = ref.watch(endKeyProvider);
    var mouseX = ref.watch(mouseXProvider);
    var mouseY = ref.watch(mouseYProvider);

    var cardPosition = ref.watch(cardProvider(start!)).position;

    // paint lines on existing nodes
    if (node.isNotEmpty) {
      for (var n in node) {
        var sourceNode = ref.watch(cardProvider(n.sourceCard)).outputNode;
        var targetNode = ref.watch(cardProvider(n.targetCard)).inputNode;
        var source = ref.watch(nodeProvider(sourceNode)).position;
        var target = ref.watch(nodeProvider(targetNode)).position;
        if (source != Offset.infinite && target != Offset.infinite) {
          // canvas.drawLine(source, target, paint);
          p.moveTo(source.dx, source.dy);
          p.lineTo(target.dx, target.dy);
          canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
        }
      }
    }

    // add line drawing with starting and ending nodes
    if (start != null && end != null) {
      var sourceNode = ref.watch(cardProvider(start)).outputNode;
      var targetNode = ref.watch(cardProvider(end)).inputNode;
      var source = ref.watch(nodeProvider(sourceNode)).position;
      var target = ref.watch(nodeProvider(targetNode)).position;
      if (source != Offset.infinite && target != Offset.infinite) {
        // canvas.drawLine(source, target, paint);
        p.moveTo(source.dx, source.dy);
        p.lineTo(target.dx, target.dy);
        canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
      }
    }

    // add line drawing with only starting node
    if (start != null) {
      var sourceNode = ref.watch(cardProvider(start)).outputNode;
      var source = ref.watch(nodeProvider(sourceNode)).position;
      // canvas.drawLine(source, Offset(mouseX, mouseY), paint);
      p.moveTo(source.dx, source.dy);
      p.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
      canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;

  @override
  bool hitTest(Offset position) {
    return p.contains(position);
  }
}
```

I'm new to flutter. Please point out any mistakes I made.

Edit 1: I changed the "Size" to the "Container", which shows a yellow box. Is there a way to update this container's position? The painter will find the right position to draw the path in the current situation. However, the Container remains at the old position.